# iOS7 - Storyboards for 6.1 and 7.0 look misaligned

Tags: ios, ios6, ios7

I am trying to get the storyboards for iOS 6.1 and 7.0 to appear normally. But for some reason the buttons from iOS 6.1 are no longer buttons and are just links. Why does that happen?

And most importantly, why did a part of the screen content on the iOS 7 screen get shifted up? Now when I try to shift it down, the iOS 6.1 content appears too low.

Here is a split screen of what is happening:

[image: screen shot]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many of the defaults for interface items have changed for iOS 7.  The standard default button is just a piece of text, with no borders.  Also, the screen displays underneath the nav bar now.  Use the edgesForExtendedLayout setting and change it from its default of UIRectEdgeAll to get the view to not show under other things.

Welcome to iOS 7!  Its not a bug-- its the new default interface.

Check out the iOS 7 transition guide [here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/AppearanceCustomization.html)

Here is where to set it in Interface Builder:
[image]

Comment: Got it...thank you! Could you just please elaborate on the edgesForExtendedLayout setting. How do I set it and where is it? :)

Comment: See my note in the answer-- you need to set the view controller's property of edgesForExtendedLayout to UIRectEdgeNone or something else that doesn't include top.

Comment: I am futzing around with trying to find how to set that property...can't seem to find it. Is it something I set in the storyboard? How do I navigate to it? Thank you!

Comment: Ok got it...figured it out - thank you very much for your help :)